# Passing entire json like objects to react component as props at one go instead of individual props

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

#### index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const comment1 = {
    "text":"Nice job",
    "author_name":"Aru",
    "avatarUrl": 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b3be63a4c2a439b013787725dfce802?d=identicon'    
}



function CompleteComment(props){
    const comment = props;
    return (
    <div className="UserInfo">      
          <img className="Avatar"
            src={comment.avatarUrl}
            alt={comment.author_name}
          />
          <div className="UserInfo-name">
            {comment.author_name}
          </div>
          <div className="comment">
             Comment: {comment.text}
          </div>
    </div>
    
    );
}
  
function App(){
    return (
        <div>
            <!-- working,but only comment text is passed not all props -->
            <CompleteComment text={comment1.text} />

            <!-- Not Working -->
            <CompleteComment comment={comment1}  />        </div>
    )
}
  

ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the above code, i am trying to pass the entire comment1 JSON object to the react component as a single prop, instead of individual props. how do I do it? I am not getting the values, also please explain why I don't get any errors also.

Comment: The first one should work and the second one won't work.

Comment: @PrayagChoraria yea, you are right. Just copy paste error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you use the "comment" prop.
Change this

```
const comment = props;
```

to

```
const { comment } = props
```

Then this will work

```
<CompleteComment comment={comment1}  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will work. You need to access `comment` of the `props` object.

```
function CompleteComment({ comment }){
    return (
    <div className="UserInfo">      
          <img className="Avatar"
            src={comment.avatarUrl}
            alt={comment.author_name}
          />
          <div className="UserInfo-name">
            {comment.author_name}
          </div>
          <div className="comment">
             Comment: {comment.text}
          </div>
    </div>
    
    );
}
```

Comment: All the answers are correct, I am not sure right one to pick.

Answer (score 1):

Use spread operator:

```
<CompleteComment {...comment1} />
```